# Arduino Nano no serial communication SIM800C

Tags: arduino, serial-port, gsm, modem

I am trying to get my SIM800C to talk with my Arduino. There is no communication happening, though.

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial at(2, 3);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  at.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // try every 2 seconds
  delay(2000);

  Serial.println("sending AT ... ");
  at.println("AT");

  while (at.available() > 0) {
    Serial.write(at.read());
  }
}
```

I am not able to get an `OK` back. SIM800C is supposed to detect the baud rate by itself.

[image: wiring of Arduino and SIM800C]

I am sure there has to be a simple stupid mistake. I just don't know what to do at this point. I obviously already checked for cable break. Out of desperation I already tried to switch `RX` and `TX`. I also tried different baud rates (whatever is within the usual limitations of `SoftwareSerial`) but it should automatically detect it once a couple of AT commands got in anyway.

Comment: Nano pin 2 (RX) should go to TX

Comment: @Juraj I already tried that as stated in the question

Comment: ok, then continue the troubleshooting with RX to RX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weird enough, the pin `PWX` on the SIM800C needs to be hooked up to a `GND` to work. It started blinking every second now and is responding to AT commands.

Also it turned out that this specific module does not ship with autobauding enabled, as stated by the SIM800C documentation. The correct baud rate is 115200.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems you need to consider:

1. Use below sample code which transfers data between PC and SIM. Sometimes SIM module would go into power down state and won't respond on any AT command but would print some results in the serial monitor.
2. As already mentioned in comments it seems that your wiring is wrong and as you declared Software Serial as `SoftwareSerial at(2, 3);` which means pin 2 is Rx on Arduino and should connect to Tx pin of SIM and pin 3 is Tx on Arduino and should connect to Rx pin of SIM. Please don't mess with the pins and connect the pins like below correctly.

> ```
> Arduino       SIM
> Rx 2   ---->  Tx
> Tx 3   ---->  Rx
> ```

3. I'm not sure if you can power on SIM800 with a 500mA USB connector, make sure that use an external 1/2 A power supply for VCC of SIM module.
4. Look at the blink speed of SIM module if it connected and powered on it would blinky with 3 seconds delay and if it blinks fast, it means that it is being restarted. Also if SIM powered on correctly it would print some info like `SIM READY`, `CALL READY`, etc.
5. Try other baud rates like `115200` and see if you get anything on power on.

I put some macro definition to make pin mappings more clear.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//SIM800 TX is connected to Arduino D2
#define SIM800_TX_PIN 2

//SIM800 RX is connected to Arduino D3
#define SIM800_RX_PIN 3



//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800
SoftwareSerial serialSIM800(SIM800_TX_PIN,SIM800_RX_PIN);

void setup() {
  //Begin serial comunication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);

  //Being serial communication witj Arduino and SIM800
  serialSIM800.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("Setup Complete!");
}

void loop() {
  //Read SIM800 output (if available) and print it in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor
  if(serialSIM800.available()){
    Serial.write(serialSIM800.read());
  }
  //Read Arduino IDE Serial Monitor inputs (if available) and send them to SIM800
  if(Serial.available()){    
    serialSIM800.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: I am at the point where I think my SIM800C is busted. I tried to get it working with an Arduino Mega and got not luck either. I switched the Arduino because `SoftwareSerial` is usually not really working at higher baud rates (like 115200) and the Mega has three more real serial ports. I also tried hooking up V_TTL to 3.3V with the Nano and 5V with the Mega respectively. Also I tried an external 5V power supply on the SIM800C.

Comment: I worked with the same module and Arduino. SoftwareSerial would work on that baud rate as I tested. The above method should work but I'm suggesting to get hands-on another module and make sure if it is fine or not. Also, remember to check the correct power voltage of your module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this module will not work in this configuration. There is a pin of V_TTL With 5V pin.. This pin enables the TTL logic converter of your GSM.. You have to connect this pin to 5V in case of arduino and to 3V in case of ESP8266.[See the pin configuration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdHo4.png)